# Cannot read property innertext of undefined for building an Array. Is it possible to null out a field if it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to loop through a SPA and grabbing the information I want. And then building an array from that. However I noticed if I run through the entire page I eventually hit `Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined for titleNodeList[i]`. Is there a way to do a try/catch or somehow null out the field if it returns undefined? It looks like some of the divs I'm scraping are incomplete and don't contain all the information, so It would have to be empty. For example it may be missing. ids.querySelectorAll(".index_game_cell_widget > .label > a.title"); or ids.querySelectorAll(".index_game_cell_widget > .user_row > a.user_link");
So Not sure how I can account for such things missing occasionally in a list

```
var Games = await page.evaluate(() => {
    var ids = document.querySelector(".grid_sizer_children");
    var titleNodeList = ids.querySelectorAll(".index_game_cell_widget > .label > a.title");
    var companyNodeList = ids.querySelectorAll(".index_game_cell_widget > .user_row > a.user_link");
    var descriptionNodeList = ids.querySelectorAll(".index_game_cell_widget > .sub.short_text");
    var imgNodeList = ids.querySelectorAll(".index_game_cell_widget > .bordered > .game_thumb > img");
    var titleLinkArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < titleNodeList.length; i++) {
    titleLinkArray[i] = {
        title: titleNodeList[i].innerText.trim(),
        link: titleNodeList[i].getAttribute("href"),
        description: descriptionNodeList[i].innerText.trim() ? descriptionNodeList[i].innerText.trim() : "",
        author: companyNodeList[i].innerText.trim() ? companyNodeList[i].innerText.trim() : "",
        images: imgNodeList[i].getAttribute('src') ? imgNodeList[i].getAttribute('src') : "",
        
    };
  }
  return titleLinkArray;
```

});

Comment: I'm not sure If I understand the question, but do you mean something like... title: titleNodeList[i] ? titleNodeList[i].innerText.trim() : null?

Comment: hi @Ambu  I think you actually understand the question! Unfortunately its not working still. Here is the exact error i"m getting. I'm wondering if its under the page.evaluate, not in the loop. :( 
`Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:13:49`

Comment: @Ambu i added it to author and images and now its working! You are a genius! Can you provide an answer so i can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
title: titleNodeList[i] ? titleNodeList[i].innerText.trim() : null
```